# Allow all cloudwatch event rules to have access to lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have been encountering a hard limit on lambda function policy when trying to provision access for a cloudwatch event rule to trigger the lambda function on a scheduled basis.

```
An error occurred (PolicyLengthExceededException) when calling the AddPermission operation: The final policy size (20670) is bigger than the limit (20480).
```

It works for a new lambda function, but eventually its policy will bloat and will hit a hard limit on the number on cloudwatch event rule that can access it.

Some said to re-create the function (delete/create), but this won't be an option in a production environment where cloudwatch events are already configured in it, resulting to the existing ones to lose access to the lambda function.

Using the aws cli, i was able to extract the policy of my lambda function, it loooks like this:

```
"Statement": [{
    "Sid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "lambda:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:xxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxx:function:xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "Condition": {
            "ArnLike": {
                "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:xxxxxxx:xxxxxx:rule/xxxxxxxxx"
            }
        }
}]
```

So i was looking onto something like for the AWS:SourceArn

```
arn:aws:events:xxxxxxx:xxxxxx:rule/*
```

To avoid hitting a hard limit, but i cannot seem to do it. Even in the lambda function itself on the console, you won't be able to create such a rule that will allow all cloudwatch event of a specified account to have access to the lambda function using a wildcard '*'.

Suggestions are much welcome. Thank you guys

Comment: Just to clarify... Is this a rule where you allow CloudWatch Events to trigger a Lambda function? Where are you putting/getting this policy? Is it related to [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon CloudWatch Events - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)? What happens if you try using the wildcard? I'd like to try and reproduce your situation, but don't have enough information of how to try it.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: yes, it is. eventually when too many cloudwatch events target the same lambda function, it hits the hard limit, and aws cannot do something about it (it cannot be increased). i haven't been able to create one, i am still finding a way at the moment how to achieve putting a wildcard on the lambda policy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was accepted without an error:

```
$ aws lambda add-permission --function-name function_name\
    --action 'lambda:InvokeFunction' --principal events.amazonaws.com \
    --statement-id '1' \
    --source-arn arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:rule/*
```

This will accept all CloudWatch Events rules.

You could instead name your rules such that the ones you want to allow can all have the same prefix in their name, eg:

```
--source-arn arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:rule/Event-*
```

Comment: thanks John, i have now implemented the solution. i am using boto3 by the way, but the same logic applies, just had to do some tweaks over my sam template. all is working now. you saved me BIG TIME!

Comment: @John Rotenstein, I've added this permission, but I still get the policy length exceeded exception when trying to add a new CloudWatch Rule. Do I need to delete all of the old permissions? It seems like CloudWatch still adds individual permissions when I add a new rule, even if the generic one is there.

Answer (score 1):

I used the above CLI command but got an error in the console, please find the attached screenshot of the error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLZEL.png). Please find below function policy of lambda:

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Id": "default",   "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "events-access",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:096280016729:function:leto_debug_log",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnLike": {
          "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:096280016729:rule/*"
        }
      }   
    }   
  ] }
```

Comment: hi, i think its just alright. i have the same on my side too. as long as your cloudwatch rules fires under a specified event, thats ok. i think the console will be improved more going forward