# Assigned function policy to lambda which allows all CloudWatch Events rule to invoke lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda

I used the above CLI command but got an error in the console, please find the attached screenshot of the error
[image]
 Please find below function policy of lambda:

```
{   "Version": "2012-10-17",   "Id": "default",   "Statement": [
    {
       "Sid": "events-access",
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": {
        "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
       },
       "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
       "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:096280016729:function:leto_debug_log",
       "Condition": {
         "ArnLike": {
           "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:096280016729:rule/*"
         }
      }
     }   ] }
```

I followed the answer from the below link but still got an error:
[Allow all cloudwatch event rules to have access to lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964484/allow-all-cloudwatch-event-rules-to-have-access-to-lambda-function)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a clue to this, is that a CloudWatch Event rule name of `*` does not appear to be valid. For example, if you try to delete this rule in the AWS lambda console area, you will get an error like this on the trigger UI area:

[image]

It would be nice if this approach was formally supported in some way, but I don't think it is. idk